# Prove that if $x^{p}+y^{p}=z^{p}$ then $p|(x+y-z)$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $x^{p}+y^{p}=z^{p}$ then $p|(x+y-z)$

I thought that maybe I could use Fermat's Last Theorem to prove this, as $p$ can only be $2$, but I don't know how to account for $x$, $y$, and $z$. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Fermat's Little Theorem: $a^p\equiv a$ (mod $p$) for all integers $a$, so if $x^p+y^p=z^p$ then 
$$ x+y\equiv z\mod p$$
or $p|(x+y-z)$.

Comment: How do you know that $p$ doesn't divide $x, y, or z$? So that you can apply Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem is still valid if $p|a$, it just reduces to $0\equiv 0$ (mod $p$).

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN Fermat's Little Theorem states that if $p$ is prime, $a\in\mathbb Z$, then $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$ or equivalently that if $p$ is prime, $a\in\mathbb Z$, $p\nmid a$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.